# Analytic spread of an ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

How to calculate analytic spread of the ideal $I=\left<xyw^2,xyz^2,xw^2+yz^2\right>$ in $\mathbb Q[x,y,z,w]?$

I think it is 3.

Comment: Macaulay2 has a command analyticSpread (http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.9/share/doc/Macaulay2/ReesAlgebra/html/_analytic__Spread.html). For this example it says the answer is 3. On the other hand $J=(xw,yz)$ seems to be a reduction of $I$ (in fact $I \subset J$ as $J$ is the radical of $I=(x^2 w^2, y^2 z^2, x w^2 + y z^2)$) and since $J$ has $2$ generators, the analytic spread must be $2$---am I missing something? (It can't be $1$ because if $I$ is integral over a principal ideal $(a)$, then $I \subset (a)$ which is impossible.)

Comment: J is not subset of I, hence J can't be a reduction of I.

Comment: Integral closure of I is (I,xyzw) and J is integrally closed. So J is not a reduction of I.

Comment: @ZachTeitler If you do not mind, could you please tell me the codes for analytic spread in macaulay2. I do not know the code for analytic spread.

Comment: Oh, I seriously messed up the definition of reduction. Sorry.

Comment: The link in my first comment goes to documentation about Macaulay2's analyticSpread command. Source code is at https://github.com/Macaulay2/M2/blob/master/M2/Macaulay2/packages/ReesAlgebra.m2 or in Macaulay2 type "code methods analyticSpread".